How to make a custom symbol `//` in LaTeX the same width as an existing symbol?
I want to define a custom slanted parallel symbol, approximately like this: // $\mathrel{/ \negmedspace /}$. The approach is to input two /, followed by a command like \! to reduce the spacing. What should the spacing be? I want this parallel symbol to have the same width as the perpendicular symbol \perp, so that they align well when appearing together in text. Through testing, I found that using \negmedspace under the default font spacing looks appropriate, almost indistinguishable to the naked eye. However, when changing fonts, the difference becomes noticeable. How can I set the spacing to make the custom symbol the same width as \perp?

Looks like
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\px{\mathrel{%
{\ooalign{$\phantom\perp\vphantom/$\cr\hidewidth$/\!\!/$\hidewidth\cr}}}}

\noindent 
$
A \px B
\\
A \perp B
\\
A // B
\\
A \mathrel{/ \negmedspace /} B
$

\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Package frenchmathprovides a\paralcommand,\newcommand\paral{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\mkern-1.75mu/\mkern1.75mu$\cr$\mkern1.75mu/\mkern-1.75mu$}}}`

@user691586 \ooalign is not the right tool for the job.

@egreg this may have to be reported to frenchmath maintainer.

@user691586 I'm sorry to say that frenchmath is just a collection of badly written macros.

Does this answer your question? Closer slanted parallel symbol

I found this question at Zhihu, a Chinese Q&A site like Quora.

This approach should work regardless of the math font.  However, this simple version will not work in the smaller script styles.  If that is an issue, please see the modified approach further down.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength\mykern
\sbox0{$\perp$}
\sbox2{$/$}
\setlength\mykern{\dimexpr\wd2+\wd2-\wd0}
\newcommand\mysym{\mathrel{/\kern-\mykern/}}
\begin{document}
$\Delta \perp \Delta \perp \Delta$

$\Delta \mysym \Delta \mysym \Delta$
\end{document}


Here is an approach that will capture the smaller script styles, as well:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\newlength\mykern
\newcommand\mysym{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{%
  \sbox0{$\SavedStyle\perp$}%
  \sbox2{$\SavedStyle/$}%
  \setlength\mykern{\dimexpr\wd2+\wd2-\wd0}%
  /\kern-\mykern/}%
}}
\begin{document}
$\Delta \perp \Delta \perp \Delta$

$\Delta \mysym \Delta \mysym \Delta$

$\scriptscriptstyle\Delta \perp \Delta \perp \Delta$

$\scriptscriptstyle\Delta \mysym \Delta \mysym \Delta$
\end{document}



The idea is to measure \perp in the current math style; however, one has to take into account the side bearing of the symbol.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\sparallel}{}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\sparallel@\relax}}

\newcommand{\sparallel@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{$\m@th#1\perp$}%
  \makebox[\dimen@][s]{$\m@th#1\mkern0.5mu/\hss/\mkern0.5mu$}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\perp B$

$A\sparallel B$

$\scriptstyle A\perp B$

$\scriptstyle A\sparallel B$

\end{document}


The alternative without \mkern1mu (on either side) is less appealing, in my opinion.


Only to link to your answer about \mathpalette which is useful to people wishing to understand your answer.
